# Getting rid of ?: operator in PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem with PHP code for survey. The code only takes one value, "answer" and if answer is not available it takes "otherAnswer". I need it to take both "answer" and "otherAnswer"

Here is the code. Thanks for help.

```
protected function convertRequestToUserAnswersArray()
{
    $answers = [];

    if ($this->request->hasArgument('answers')) {
        /** @noinspection PhpUnhandledExceptionInspection */
        $requestAnswers = $this->request->getArgument('answers');

        /** @noinspection PhpWrongForeachArgumentTypeInspection */
        foreach ($requestAnswers as $questionUid => $requestAnswer) {
            $answers[$questionUid] = $requestAnswer['answer'] ?: $requestAnswer['otherAnswer'];
        }
    }

    return $answers;
}
```

Comment: Then concatenate it, or put it in an array? What did you tried? What problems you encountered?

Comment: try this : $answers[$questionUid] = $requestAnswer['answer'] ? $requestAnswer['answer']  : $requestAnswer['otherAnswer'];

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar thanks, but it still takes only "answer".

Answer (score 0):

Try to append both answers. If you want both answers you don't need to use ternary operator

```
protected function convertRequestToUserAnswersArray()
{
    $answers = [];

    if ($this->request->hasArgument('answers')) {
        /** @noinspection PhpUnhandledExceptionInspection */
        $requestAnswers = $this->request->getArgument('answers');

        /** @noinspection PhpWrongForeachArgumentTypeInspection */
        foreach ($requestAnswers as $questionUid => $requestAnswer) {
            $answers[$questionUid] = $requestAnswer['answer'] +' '+ $requestAnswer['otherAnswer'];
        }
    }

    return $answers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We do not know how the `$answers` is going to be used. Because returning both answer and otherAnswer requires `$answers` to be array. Which means any user of `$answers` must be refactored.

Something like this might work:

```
$answers[$questionId] = ["answer" => $requestAnswer["answer"], "otherAnswers" => requestAnswer["otherAnswer"] ]
```

Just add some checking mechanism for the key existence.

Or you can concatenate it as suggested in another SO answer.

Comment: $answer is going to be written into database.
The code gives error: setUserAnswerFromRequestData() must be of the type string, null given

Answer (score 0):

As you said you want both values then you can store into array as like below

```
$answers[$questionUid][] = $requestAnswer['answer'];
$answers[$questionUid][] = $requestAnswer['otherAnswer'];
```

By using above script `$answers` would have both values against `$questionUid`

Comment: think that is known as the `Elvis Operator` '-)

Comment: @RamRaider true, my mistake I am going to edit my answer

Comment: The code gives error: setUserAnswerFromRequestData() must be of the type string, null given

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$answers[$questionUid]` is an array, You can try to push the values to it:

```
/** @noinspection PhpWrongForeachArgumentTypeInspection */
foreach ($requestAnswers as $questionUid => $requestAnswer) {
    $answers[$questionUid] = $requestAnswer['answer'] . '----' . $requestAnswer['otherAnswer'];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code gives error:
setUserAnswerFromRequestData() must be of the type string, null given